# Initialize mocks via @Mock before @Rule

Tags: java, junit, mockito, dropwizard

I have a test class which is testing a Dropwizard resource and using the JUnit test rule `ResourceTestRule`. It sets up many mocks and I want to replace this idiom:

`Foo foo = mock(Foo.class);`

which is a bit verbose with this

`@Mock Foo foo;`

However the Dropwizard `ResourceTestRule` needs to reference these mocks like so

```
@Rule
public ResourceTestRule resources = ResourceTestRule.builder()
        .addResource(new BarResource(foo))
        .build();
```

My problem is that the `@Rule` runs before `@Mock` initializes the mock, and so `foo` is null when `BarResource` is instantiated, and I then I get null pointer exceptions when my tests run.

Here's a minimal example without Dropwizard stuff to demonstrate the issue:

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.model.Statement;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestTest {
    @Mock String foo;

    @Rule
    public TestRule testRule = new TestRule() {
        {
            assert foo != null; // <<< this assertions fails
        }

        @Override
        public Statement apply(Statement statement, Description description) {
            return statement;
        }
    };

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

If I could control the ordering between `@Mock` and `@Rule` I could avoid this problem. Or perhaps there's an alternative I'm not thinking of.

Any advice appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you can use `MockitoRule` instead, since runner is run after test class is initialized. but you should put the assertion in your `apply` method because of `MockitoRule` will inject mocks when `start` is called.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I will look into `MockitoRule` when I'm back in the office Monday but from skimming the Javadocs it might not work for my use case: I need the dependencies to be initialized and passed to classes which are then passed to the Dropwizard `ResourceTestRule` which is instantiated when the test class is, as pointed out by obecker in their answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem with the `@Rule` annotation but with the initialization of the member variables of the test class. The rule instance (`resources` or `testRule`) will be initialized when the test instance is created. This happens even if there is no `@Rule` annotation attached to it (this is simple java logic: when an object instance is constructed, all its member variables will be initialized during the construction).

So when Mockito creates the `foo` mock, `resources` or `testRule` have already been created. This behavior won't change if you use the `MockitoRule` instead.
And the `@Rule` annotation just tells JUnit to use the created object as a rule, it doesn't control the creation of the rule.

So I guess the only solution is indeed to create the `foo` mock also during the initialization of the test, i.e. with `Foo foo = mock(Foo.class)`

Comment: haha of course, this makes total sense! embarrassed I didn't realize this before posting the question, I got muddled by all the annotations between JUnit and DW. thanks